# Does the opponent get to draw up to a full hand after being attacked with Pilebunker?

Tags: flash-duel

One of the abilities of the *Jefferson DeGrey* character is *Pilebunker*.

Screencapped from *Tabletop Simulator*

[image: Pilebunker screencapped from Tabletop Simulator]

> [Triggered when] You *retreat* from a *dashing strike*
>
> If you're 4 spaces from that opponent after *retreating*, you may immediately *attack* (with 4s).

Now normally when somebody blocks they don't get to draw those cards back until their next turn, but this action is usually carried out during the opponents turn.  In this case, since the block is performed during their own turn, do players blocking a *Pilebunker* attack get to draw a full hand on their next turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The turn order is:

1. Do one of these: move, push, attack, or dashing strike.
2. If you did an attack or dashing strike, your opponent *must* respond or he loses the round.
3. Discard any cards played this turn.
4. Draw until you have 5 cards, then your turn ends.

Your opponent playing Pilebunker is part of step 2. You still get step 4 this turn (if you successfully blocked), so you still get to draw back up to a full hand of 5 cards.

Source: [Rulebook](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/50f14d35e4b0d70ab5fc4f24/t/53f85928e4b017241944422a/1408784680430/flash_duel_2nd_ed_rulebook4-1.pdf)